# Why can't I add a String and a Boolean to my arrayList (Java/Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, boolean

I'm trying to add a String (To do activity) and a boolean (toggle is urgent, untoggled is not urgent). I did this by creating a class called ToDos and having String and Boolean within the class itself.

However, I'm getting errors saying that the String should be a ToDos (the name of the class) and I have no idea how to circumvent this.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidlabs;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;
    EditText editText;
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    Switch switch1;

    ArrayList<ToDos> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        taskList.add(new ToDos("Mow the lawn",false));
        taskList.add(new ToDos("Do groceries", false));
        taskList.add(new ToDos("Change oil", true));

        //variables
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TheListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter = new ListAdapter());

        //onClick
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                taskList.add(new ToDos(taskList.add(editText.getText().toString()), switch1.isChecked()));

                editText.setText("");

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    //adapter
    class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return taskList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ToDos getItem(int position) {
            return taskList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View old, ViewGroup parent) {
            View newView =old;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            if(newView==null){
                newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            }
            TextView textview= newView.findViewById(R.id.textgoeshere);

            textview.setText(getItem(position).text);
            if(getItem(position).IsUrgent){
                textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            return newView;
        }
    }
   public class ToDos {
        public String text;
        public Boolean IsUrgent;

        public ToDos(String text, Boolean IsUrgent) {
            this.text = text;
            this.IsUrgent = IsUrgent;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is specifically with this line :

```
taskList.add(new ToDos(taskList.add(editText.getText().toString()),switch1.isChecked()));
```

However I've tried everything I can think of and I'm stumped. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect as you have `taskList.add` twice

try

```
taskList.add(new ToDos(editText.getText().toString(),switch1.isChecked());
```

Comment: Oh my god... So simple yet so effective. Thank you SO much! Can't believe I missed that.